# Encontrar palabra clave en archivo tipo "Lookup table" en DOS

Tags: batch

Estoy tratando de crear un script en batch (consola Windows) que analice un archivo de texto plano estilo "lookup table" el cual contiene una serie de líneas en formato "PALABRA_CLAVE VALOR".

Tengo problemas para comprobar con el comando ***find*** o ***findstr*** si la palabra clave ya existe en dicho archivo.

Supongamos que existe una palabra clave "SECOND_ENTRY" y se quiere comprobar si existe "SECOND" para crearla como nueva clave.

Pues find detecta como que esa palabra clave ya existe, pero esto no es cierto, simplemente existe otra que contiene ese string, pero no es ese string concretamente.

Así pues, busco una solución para que analice la cadena exacta tal cual va antes del primer espacio.

Leyendo un poco la ayuda, probé con el modificador /X, pero este analiza toda la línea, por lo que no vale para este caso, y luego esté el /C que parecía que sería la solución, ya que el enunciado dice que analiza la cadena literalmente, pero no consigo que funcione, solo consigo que diga "se ha omitido el operador /C".

Dejo un ejemplo del código a continuación:

```
findstr /C "%KEY%" %FILE%>null
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
echo ERROR! The provided KEY already exists in the FILE! please, Insert a new one.
```

El archivo estilo LOOKUP:

```
FIRST_ENTRY this is a sample for the first entry
SECOND_ENTRY another entry for our ets
THIRD_ENTRY blah blah blaaah
FOURTH_ENTRY jdajhsdjhsad
FIFTH ???
NEW_ENTRY this is the value
```

Answer (score 1):

Vale, me respondo a mi mismo, ya he descubierto donde estaba el fallo.

En vez de:

```
findstr /C "%KEY%" %FILE%>null
```

Es asi:

```
findstr /c:"%KEY% " "..\%FILE%">null
```

Haciendo esto, no falla el modificador /C y se puede detectar unicamente la palabra clave.